# Forcing timeline to continue anyway if not triggered by user (AS2)

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am making an interactive ad and I have a button mc in flash using ActionScript 2 which when dragged to a target triggers the rest of the timeline to play the animation. But what I would like to do in addition to this is force the animation to play anyway after 10 seconds incase the user decides not to click and drag.

```
stop();

myButton.onEnterFrame = function() {
    this._x = 23;
};
myButton.onPress = function() {
    delete this.onEnterFrame;
    startDrag(this, false, 30, this._y, 280, this._y);
    onEnterFrame = function () {
        gotoAndStop(Math.round(myButton._x - 25));
    };
};
myButton.onRelease = myButton.onReleaseOutside = function () {
    stopDrag();

    this.onEnterFrame = function() {
        this._x = _currentframe + 25;


    if (eval(this._droptarget) == target) {
    this._x += (280-this._x) * 0.5;
    }
    else {//if (eval(this._droptarget) != model) {
    this._x += (23-this._x) * 0.5;
    }


    };
};
```

This may have a simple answer but I am still learning the basics of AS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var tenSecondInterval = setInterval( doThisAfterTenSeconds, 10000 );

function doThisAfterTenSeconds():Void
{
    clearInterval( tenSecondInterval );

    // respond
}
```